# Какой хук использовать при создании заказа WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, paypal

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при создании заказа через PayPal, количество товаров из заказа отнималось из остатков самого товара. Функцию я сделал, и она рабочая на 100%.

```
add_action( 'save_post_shop_order', 'create_invoice_for_wc_order',10,3 );
function create_invoice_for_wc_order($order_id) {

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id);

        // Iterating through each "line" items in the order
        foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_data) {

            // Get an instance of corresponding the WC_Product object
            $product = $item_data->get_product();
            $product_name = $product->get_name(); // Get the product name
            $item_quantity = $item_data->get_quantity(); // Get the item quantity
            $all_qua = $product->get_stock_quantity();

            $diff = $all_qua - $item_quantity;

            wc_update_product_stock($product, $diff);

            $item_total = $item_data->get_total(); // Get the item line total

            // Displaying this data (to check)
            echo 'Product name: '.$product_name.' | Quantity: '.$item_quantity.' | All_Quantity: '.$all_qua.' | Item total: '. number_format( $item_total, 2 );
            // $txt = fopen( "C:\\ospanel\\domains\\joke.fuu\\wp-content\\themes\\storefront\\hhh.txt" , "w");
            // fwrite($txt, $new_status);

        }

}
```

Но! На какой хук это повесить, чтоб оно срабатывало на создании поста? save_post срабатывает только на обновлении, wp_insert_post - тоже.

Пробовал так же хуки от WooCommerce, типа woocommerce_new_order, тоже безрезультатно.

---

Проблема решена! И вот в чем заключалось ее решение:

На этапе создания заказа, используя "`woocommerce_new_order`" я еще не получал товары, которые есть в этом заказе. Чтобы получить товары, которые появляются в новом заказе, нужно использовать хук - "`woocommerce_checkout_order_processed`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При создании заказа срабатывает акция `woocommerce_new_order`. Для подключения своей функции используйте код

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'create_invoice_for_wc_order' );
```

Эта акция срабатывает при создании заказа и через PayPal, и через Cash on Delivery (проверил оба метода), и по хуку `save_post_shop_order` и по `woocommerce_new_order` (тоже проверил) - т.е. всегда. Ниже - картинка из отладчика, с точкой останова в строке 2323. Выполнение кода перехвачено отладчиком, что отмечено синим фоном строки.

Ожидаемого вами echo я, естественно, не увидел - там сплошные редиректы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не знаю, что вы там смогли сломать, чтобы у вас не срабатывал этот хук. Сказать сложно. Смените тему на стандартную, отключите все плагины, кроме WooCommerce.

Если критерием работает/не работает является echo - то это совсем ненадёжный подход к отладке. Более того, echo в ajax может сломать код. Включите хотя бы [стандартный отладочный лог](https://wp-kama.ru/id_7791/debag-v-wordpress-wp_debug.html).

Comment: "Пробовал так же хуки от WooCommerce, типа woocommerce_new_order"

Comment: Функция просто не срабатывает

Comment: Где у вас находится приведённый в вопросе код?

Comment: function.php самой темы. Там же, я чуть ниже вешаю эту же функцию, только не с отниманием, а с добавлением, на хуки woocommerce_order_status_processing и тому подобные, все отрабатывает нормально. Возможно, именно экшн с хуком создания поста нужно инициализировать в другом месте?

Comment: Ничего не понял. С каким отниманием? Покажите полный код, относящийся к вопросу.

Comment: В этой функции я отнимаю значения. В такой же функции и вместо "-" ставлю "+", но это роли не играет, так как в данном случае, функция вообще не срабатывает. Я просто сказал о том, что хуки на изменение статуса уже существующего заказа из functions.php - работают. 

Тут проблема либо в выборе хука, либо в месте его использования.

Comment: Возможно, шлюз Paypal использует другие хуки для создания поста.

Comment: Шлюз PayPal не использует никаких других хуков, он работает как часть WooCommerce. Хуки рабочие, смотрите дополнение к ответу.

Comment: Дополнение посмотрел. Установил с чистого листа локально Wordpress, оставил только WooCommerce, использовал стандартную тему.

Echo мне был нужен раньше, для других целей, самоцелью он не был и ничего я от него не ждал. Для просмотра результатов я записывал данные в файл, так же WP_DEBUG был включен.

Результат тот же. Ошибок никаких, товары не отнимаются.

Comment: Вопрос был о чём - срабатывает ли хук. Я вам ответил доказательно. Новый вопрос "почему не отнимаются товары" надо задать отдельно.

Comment: Я понял, спасибо. Я убедился, что хук работает. Сейчас задам новый вопрос.

Comment: Проблема решена, этот вопрос я отредактировал, следующих не требуется. Большое спасибо за помощь, KAGG Design. Проблема была все же в хуке)